# How to run a .sh script in terminal by double-clicking?

Tags: linux, bash, sh, double-click

I have a .sh script that I would like to run in a terminal window upon being double-clicked. This is the contents of the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "$(dirname "$(readlink -fn "$0")")"
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.1.19.jar nogui
```

Is there any way to modify the script so that the output could be displayed back to the user?

I have looked online for any potential solutions, and the closest I have found is [this](https://www.ikkaro.com/en/como-ejecutar-archivos-sh/) article, which takes advantage of options that are not provided to me by my distro (Kubuntu). I have also attempted to set the file to, by default, open with a terminal, however the script does not run.

Comment: don't use `nogui`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one solution is crating a `*.desktop` file here:

```
$ cat path-to-script.desktop   
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=Click-Script
Icon=utilities-terminal
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "bash -c './script.sh;$SHELL'"
Categories=Application;
```

Comment: Thank you, just for clarification, does the "gnome-terminal" specification change if I am using a different desktop environment, i.e. KDE Plasma?

Comment: Well I believe yes since `gnome-terminal` will not be available with other desktop environments